# Recycler view of vertical scrolling list with Horizontal scrollable row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want an RecyclerView in which we have vertical scrollable list of items.
From this scrollable list of items some should have ability to scroll in horizontal direction.
As shown in below image
[image]

can anyone please guide me how to do it?

Thank You.

Comment: Because there is no method to add footer to the recyclerview...you can create an item with horizontal scrollview and inflate it in the adapter to make it look like a footer.

Answer (score 5):

> Custom LayoutManagers
>
> - StaticGridLayoutManager - 2D scrolling grid with variable column    count based on data set. Window of visible (non-recycled) views is
>     determined statically.
> - DynamicGridLayoutManager - 2D scrolling grid    where window of visible views is determined dynamically. Results in    fewer views in
>     memory, but scrolling performance is questionable.

I have met the same problem and I found this library. Maybe it will help you.
https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground

More detail about RecyclerView LayoutManager: http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/

p/s: For your case http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/

Comment: The problem is, that the two way view from lucasr, has no example or tutorial... But maybe we should go on and try for ourselves

Answer (score -1):

Since this seems to be a commonly asked problem, I thought I'll share my simple implementation of this. It is quite easy to achieve this using a RecyclerView. I did this while trying to create a horizontal list of scrollable images when a picture was taken using the device camera. I have pasted the relevant section of the adapter.

I used a RecyclerView that used a LinearLayoutManager with orientation set to horizontal.

The adapter itself is quite simple and is (please note only relevant sections are here):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.ebay.lockers.R;
import com.ebay.lockers.utils.AsyncDrawable;
import com.ebay.lockers.utils.BitmapUtils;
import com.ebay.lockers.utils.BitmapWorkerTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sunil on 6/17/2016.
 */
public class ImagesHorizontalListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesHorizontalListAdapter.ImagesViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<File> imageFiles;

    public ImagesHorizontalListAdapter(Context context, List<File> imageFiles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageFiles = imageFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesHorizontalListAdapter.ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.simple_image_view, parent, false);
        ImagesViewHolder viewHolder = new ImagesViewHolder(layout);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ImagesHorizontalListAdapter.ImagesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int availableWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int imageWidth = availableWidth/4; // Number of images to be shown by default
        int imageHeight = imageWidth*4/3;
        final int minDimenForScaling = Math.min(imageWidth, imageHeight);

        holder.image.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadBitmap(imageFiles.get(position), holder.image, minDimenForScaling, minDimenForScaling);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageFiles.size();
    }

    public void loadBitmap(File file, ImageView imageView, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        if(BitmapUtils.cancelPotentialWork(file, imageView)) {
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // The second Bitmap parameter is a placeholder image
            // Should consider animation; TO DO --
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(context.getResources(), null, task);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            task.execute(file);
        }
    }

    public static class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is an image
        ImageView image;

        public ImagesViewHolder(View layout) {
            super(layout);
            this.image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked by op

Comment: It provides him with a blue print for the solution. The OP asked for a guide which is precisely what I did. Please analyze the question critically.

Comment: The op asked about a recyclerview which would contain items vertically and of those item some of the rows would have multiple items as shown in the image. Your solution is only covering the first part that is displaying items in vertically or horizontally. It doesn't cover what he asked. Please see the question again