# Android two way scrolling Listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Let's say I have 100 rows of data to show in a ListView. So far no problem. I have a custom adapter for each row, that has a TextView for a date, a TextView for a sequence number and NOW 60 more TextViews, mostly having a two digit number.

How can I get a horizontal scroll to show all these 60 numbers, BUT, the vertical scroll for the Listview should still work, to scroll down from 1 to 100 row, and also, all rows shown on the screen shall scroll horizontal at the same time, not that only one row will scroll horizontal.

Had tried TwoWayView, but only allows to define one direction of scroll.

Comment: This seems the same as or at least similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/31129702/49489 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a horizontal scrolling list as each ListItem. Although, there are several horizontal scrolling view options, I would recommend using a Recyclerview with a LinearLayoutManager and orientation set to HORIZONTAL.

The general idea is you need a horizontal list as a list item.